# Web video playback stops, only reboot helps

Tags: windows, windows-8, video, video-playback

This happen every other day. I watch a YT video, it suddenly halts and I can't get it to play anymore. When it happens, it affects all browsers, except IE plays a couple seconds and then halts.  Actually, all the web video players suffer this, not just YT. Only reboot helps; logoff-login does not.

Any idea what it is and how to fix it without reboot, if not prevent it from ever happening?

Comment: any idea what video format is in use? do CPU usage, RAM, and Temperature appear normal when the video stalls?

Comment: @FrankThomas: no idea. It's Youtube, must be h264, I suppose? And yes, all those parameters appear normal. No anomalies other than video playback. The YT player just displays the "loading" animation endlessly and no playback occurs.

Comment: YouTube supports a number of formats including WebM, VP8/9, MOV, HTML5, etc. I think it still even supports flash. If you have a codec problem, then isolating the codec in use will be critical to a resolution. https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en

Comment: @FrankThomas: that's an interesting thought, but how do I find out?